# can not get Advertising ID Provider in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-asynctask, ads

i want to get Advertising ID for my app, which i have no success.

```
import androidx.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient;
import androidx.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdInfo;

public class addUtilsJava extends AsyncTask<Context, String, String> {

    static String TAG = "addUtilsJava";


    private String getIdThread(Context context) {

        AdvertisingIdInfo adInfo = null;
        try {
            adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context).get();

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (adInfo != null) {
            final boolean isLAT = adInfo.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled();
            return adInfo.getId();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Context... contexts) {
        return getIdThread(contexts[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (s != null)
            Log.d(TAG, s);
    }
}
```

it throw exception that suggesting me `androidx.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdNotAvailableException: No Advertising ID Provider available`. i tried with 2 mobile phone and emulator all with same result.


thanks in advance

ps: i check the solution provided in android doc but **it won't work for** me https://developer.android.com/training/articles/ad-id

and i rather have a solution that don't require dependency

Comment: did you try without androidx using the support lib? Also does your phone has the Play Services?

Comment: i did not try with old gms-services and all my phone have play services

Comment: Do you have access to the play store on those phones?

Comment: i check that with normal phone that have play service enable and i can see ads-id in setting

Comment: I'm sorry but was those phones the same that those having the issue? 
Definitevely you need to assert that it's not related to the androidx lib, and also that using a blank new project you don't have the issue. If you have the issue in a new standalone app, you can share this app to the question.

Comment: I also have the same issue. I'm able to get ad ID using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier` lib, but I'm getting `AdvertisingIdNotAvailableException` when trying to use `androidx` lib. Obviously, the issue is in androidx lib itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Code..for me working..

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        AdvertisingIdClient.Info idInfo = null;
                        try {
                            idInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(getApplicationContext());
                        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        String advertId = null;
                        try{
                            advertId = idInfo.getId();
                        }catch (NullPointerException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return advertId;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String advertId) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), advertId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                };
                task.execute();

}

}
```

build.gradle added dependencies

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:18.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Question is related to AndroidX. Answer suggests using Google Play Services artifact. Although solution might work - this is not an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

add the following lib into your gradle and get the AdId from there instead. It works perfectly for me

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it with callbacks as it's described in [training sample](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/ad-id). Make all calls from main thread. Hope it would help

Comment: i test that not working and i don't want to add dependency just to use it once

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working solution in `Kotlin`.

First of all, Add this rule to your app module level `build.gradle` file in dependency:
   `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:11.8.0'`

This is AddUtilsJava class:

```
package com.example.myapplication


import android.content.Context
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.util.Log
import com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException
import java.io.IOException

class AddUtilsJava : AsyncTask<Context, String, String>() {

    private fun getIdThread(context: Context): String? {
        var idInfo: AdvertisingIdClient.Info? = null
        try {
            idInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context.applicationContext)
        } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesRepairableException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        var advertId: String? = null
        try {
            advertId = idInfo!!.id
        } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return advertId
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg contexts: Context): String? {
        return getIdThread(contexts[0])
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(s: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(s)
        if (s != null)
            Log.d(TAG, s)
    }

    companion object {
        internal var TAG = "addUtilsJava"
    }
}
```

This is build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:11.8.0' //for ads

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'
}
```

Comment: Question is related to AndroidX. Answer suggests using Google Play Services artifact. Although solution might work - this is not an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You use bellow method to get AAID of your device. Call bellow method inside onCreate method

```
public void getAAID()
{
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                AdvertisingIdClient.Info adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(MyActivity.this);
                String myId = adInfo != null ? adInfo.getId() : null;

               Log.i("UIDMY",myId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.e("error", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Complete information:- [How to Get AAID for Facebook Ads?](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/get-android-advertisement-id-aaid-programmatically/)